# Memory management in replace function

Tags: c, string, replace, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to make a replace function in C. I know there are many out there that I could copy, but I decided to make my own function in order to practice.

However, I'm stuck at this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void replace_content(char *rep, char *with, char **text) {
  int len_rep = strlen(rep);
  int len_with = strlen(with);
  char *p = *text;
  int new_text_size = 0;
  char *new_text = malloc(new_text_size);
  do {
    if (!strncmp(p, rep, len_rep)) {
      new_text_size += len_with;
      new_text = (char *) realloc(new_text, new_text_size + 1);
      strcat(new_text, with);
      p += len_rep;
    } else {
      new_text_size++;
      new_text = (char *) realloc(new_text, new_text_size);
      new_text[new_text_size-1] = *p;
      p++;
    }
  } while (*p != '\0');
  *text = malloc(new_text_size);
  strcpy(*text, new_text);
}

int main() {
  printf("Testing a replace function:\n");
  char *text =
    "<serviceName>\n"
    "  <label1>a</label1>\n"
    "  <label2>b</label2>\n"
    "  <label3>c</label3>\n"
    "</serviceName>\n";
  printf("Before replace:\n%s", text);
  replace_content("serviceName>", "serviceNameResponse>", &text);
  printf("After replace:\n%s", text);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output I'm seeing so far:

```
Testing a replace function:
Before replace:
<serviceName>
  <label1>a</label1>
  <label2>b</label2>
  <label3>c</label3>
</serviceName>
After replace:
<0�serviceNameRespons
  <label1>a</label1>
  <label2>b</label2>
  <label3>c</label3>
</serviceNameResponse>
```

My guess is that I'm doing something wrong with dynamic memory, but the more I look into my code the more confused I am.

Comment: For starters you have a memory leak, as you don't `free` the memory allocated for `new_text`. On the other hand you don't need to `free` it immediately, as you could simply do `*text = *new_text`.

Comment: `new_text = malloc(1); new_text[0] = 0;` would seem a better opener than what you have now (admittedly sans-error-checking, but you get the point, I hope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two statements are problematic:

```
new_text = (char *) realloc(new_text, new_text_size + 1);
strcat(new_text, with);
```

The first problem is that you should never assign back directly to the pointer you reallocate. That is because `realloc` may fail and return `NULL`, making you lose the original pointer.

The second problem is that `new_text` doesn't initially point to a null-terminated string, which makes the call to `strcat` [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There is also a problem in the `else` branch:

```
new_text = (char *) realloc(new_text, new_text_size);
new_text[new_text_size-1] = *p;
```

Besides the same problem with reassigning back to the pointer being reallocated, you don't terminate the string in `new_text`.

Comment: This is it. Unfortunaly I posted a version of my code that was a bit mingled up, but the key to all my problems was the copy of the character in the else branch and the lack of null-termination there. The first < was copied correctly, but it was not null-terminated, so the strcat started to concatenate in the first null-string that was available.

Answer (score 0):

May the reason is malloc(0) in line 10 `char *new_text = malloc(new_text_size);`.

> The malloc() function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to
>   the  allocated memory.  The memory is not initialized.  If size is  0,
>   then  malloc()  returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that
>   can later be successfully passed to free().

I suggest using `char *new_text = NULL;` instead.